# How to save incoming variables from serial port into a list

Tags: tcl

I want to save 7 variables incoming over a serial port. The transmission starts with an empty line, followed by 7 lines, each consisting of a single variable. No blanks but a carriage return at every line end. Each variable can also consists of blanks. This is carried out repeatedly.
If the empty line would cause a problem, it coud be omitted in my external device.

```
#!/ usr /bin/env wish

console show
set Term(Port) com5
set Term(Mode) "9600,n,8,1"

set result [list]
set data {}

proc receiver {chan} {

    set data [gets $chan]
    concat {*}[split $data \n]
    set ::result [split $data "\n"]
    #puts $data
    #puts $::result
    #foreach Element $::result {     
    #puts $Element}
    #puts "Element 0  [lindex $::result 0]"
    #puts "Element 1  [lindex $::result 1]"

    return
}

 set chan [open $Term(Port) r+]
 fconfigure $chan -mode $Term(Mode) -translation binary -buffering none -blocking 0
 fileevent $chan readable [list receiver $chan]
```

`puts $data` shows the following:

```
START

ChME3    

562264  

Lok3     
Lok4      


Lok6
```

All the 7 variables are visible but with empty lines inbetween. The empty line between "Lok4" and "Lok6" seems to be ok, since this is a variable consisting of blanks.

I tried to create a list with `set ::result [split $data "\n"]`. But that isn't working properly. With `foreach Element $::result {puts $Element}` the console shows the 7 variables:

```
START     
ChME3     
562264    
Lok3      
Lok4      
.          
Lok6
```

I have inserted the point between Lok4 and Lok6 manually here in the blockquote just for display purposes. In reality it's a variable consisting of only blanks.

Despite it looks like a list, if I try 
`puts "Element 0  [lindex $::result 0]"
puts "Element 1  [lindex $::result 1]"`

it shows

```
Element 0 START  
Element 1        
Element 0 ChME3  
Element 1        
Element 0 562264
```

and so on.
Element 1 remains empty and Element 0 is consecutively assigned with each variable.
So it is clearly not a list. But I wonder, why `foreach Element $::result {puts $Element}`seems to work? What do I have to change to get a real list?

Comment: Do you mean a list as a data structure or a list as a GUI concept?

Comment: I mean a list as data structure

Comment: Thx for the updated snippet. There seems to be confusion about the timing in your script: the trailing loop + `puts $Element` are executed at a time (= too early) when the `receiver` proc has not been called yet. It is a callback, in the end, to an inherently asynchronous event (see the `-blocking 0` setting of your serial channel): the `result` variable will only be assigned an expected value for the first time when the `receiver` callback has been triggered once, so you would place your debugging line (`puts`) in there; see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and pls excuse my delayed response. I was busy othertwise. If I do it exactly according to your proposal, it doesn't look like a list. The variables in question are mostly garbled and in between is scattered a huge amount of curly brackets. And it's not consistent, every "list" starts differently. I think - among other things- , it's somehow not "synchronised". Every incoming variable ends with a CR. Shouldn't we use this for "synchronisation"?

Comment: Hans, when you mean end-of-line characters by CR, and this is what you expect to receive from your serial device, then you would use [`gets`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), and not `read`: `set ::results [gets $chan]` in `receiver`. `read` will not stop at end-of-line characters, therefore the garbling. Unless you show what you want to see ("variables", "list"?) and what you are actually seeing, it will be remain difficult to help, I am afraid.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly: `read` -> `gets`

Comment: That's a breakthrough. I see now my variables. But they are still surrounded by lots of curly brackets.
To get rid of them, I modified the code as you can see in my updated code. The variables are now correctly shown in a column,
but every variable still starts and ends with a curly bracket. With the command "foreach Element $::result { puts $Element}"       
the brackets are gone. But something is still wrong. If I try to assign an element of the list to a variable as follows
"lassign $::result var0 var1 var2" each variable is consecutively assigned to var0, all other var remains empty.

Comment: What does `data` contain exactly, before you run `[split]` on it? Why splitting on newline characters (`\n`), when data is meant to contain a single line (remember, you use `gets`)? My guessing is that your use of `[split]` is not needed at all, rather, it distorts the data retrieved from the device by turning it into a single-element list; therefore, the curly braces that you observe. Just stop using `[split]`.

Comment: Ah, is it about "variables shown ... in a column", therefore the `split`? Then you need to sanitize the result of [split] to flatten the resulting list of elements, for example: `concat {*}[split $data \n]`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478416/converting-columns-in-a-list-in-tcl-script

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. "data" contains all the incoming variables, each in a new line. I have overseen this totally. I was using "split" earlier in order to create a list. Now,how can I retrieve these individual variables from "data" and save each of them in a particular variable? Or create a list?

Comment: mrcalvin, I just noticed your link. It looks promising. At the moment I don't have spare time. I will look into it later and will keep you informed. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi mrcalvin, I'm back again. I think I haven't expressed myself clearly enough for other people to be able to understand what exactly I want. Therefore I have updated my question in the hope, that it's now more understandable. Sorry for bothering you constantly.

Comment: The updated question is an improvement, thx. However, you did not try what I suggested: `concat {*}[split $data \n]`. See also my updated answer.

Comment: That's because I don't understand what it exactly does and where I have to put it in the code. Do I still need "set ::result [split $data "\n"] "

Comment: I have inserted your suggestion after "set data [gets $chan]", but that doesn't make any difference. By the way, how can I insert a code into this comment.

Comment: mrcalvin, I have updated my code with your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't make any difference. I have tried different other things but wihtout success. As a beginner I have problems understanding the countless arguments within the different commands. Which are also - for my understanding - not clearly explained in the various manuals I have consulted. I would appreciate it very much, if could help me furthermore.

Comment: Hi Hans, you have to assign the result of the `concat` command call to some variable that you continue working on. See my updated answer. Did you work through the [Tcl tutorial](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+0)? You need to sort out some basics, while diving into your application.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm unable to retrieve it. Or do I have to create an own new list?

The result is retrieved using [`gets`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm) and turned into a list using [`split`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm) in this one step:

```
[split [gets $chan] {}]
```

To stash this list away, assign the list value to a variable that is scoped beyond the surrounding proc, e.g., a global or namespace variable:

```
set ::result [split [gets $chan] {}]
```

In context:

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    set data [gets $chan]
    set ::result [concat {*}[split $data \n]]
    # set ::result [split [gets $chan] {}]
    # puts $::result; # debug print-out
    return
}
```

### GUI integration

> I have already created such a GUI where I want to put these variables
>    into labels

Connect your label widget to the global variable `::result`, so the label becomes updated upon changes to the variable in `proc receiver`.

```
label .l -textvar ::result
```

Comment: Thanks mrcalvin for your quick response. Maybe I misunderstand you. I have replaced the existing procedure "proc receiver..." by your proposal but that doesn't work. The command  "puts $result" shows a blank

Comment: Can you pls update your code snippet, showing where exactly you expect `puts $result` to work? What exactly are you trying to achieve, generally? why are you working with the Tk snippet if you don't want to print out the result to the GUI?

Comment: I have set "result" as a global variable and placed the "puts $result" at the end of the code. My intention is, to print out these variables each in a fix position on the GUI and update them every time new values arrive rather than as a scrolled text. I have already created such a GUI where I want to put these variables into labels. I chose this Tk snippet, because I thought, it would be easier to modify it than start from scratch. Beginner's thinking!

Comment: Unfortunately Idon't know, how to update the code snippet

Comment: Use the `-textvar` option on your lable, see my updated answer.

Comment: I managed to rectify the garbled mess and added the modified sode snippet.

Comment: So I don't post a new question. mrcalvin could you pls have look.

Comment: I understand your updated answer about the label widget . But before I can do that, I need a proper list of the variables,  which is not the case.
If I run this modified code snippet as shown, the console doesn't show anything. Only when I move the puts command into the proc receiver,
the console displays a list. But this list doesen't contain variables (6 in my case) but a huge amount of single characters of all af the variables.
Every of these variables is sent on a new line. I think, this should be the criterion to retrieve the complete variable rather than each single character.