# How to access a list from proc in global space

Tags: tcl

I need `LIST` outside of proc for further procession. But `puts $LIST` shows an error message `no such variable`.

I have also tried `upvar 0# LIST LIST` instead of `global` with the same result.

I suspect, the troublemaker is calling proc with "list ..... If I ommit "list" in calling proc, the command `global` does what it should,
but of course the code as a whole isn't working properly anymore.

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    global LIST
    set data [gets $chan]
    set LIST [split $data ,]  
}

puts $LIST  

set chan [open com5 r]
fconfigure $chan -mode "9600,n,8,1" -blocking 1 -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $chan readable [list receiver $chan]
```

How can I get access to `LIST` in the global space outside of proc?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is partially that the variable hasn't been written at all yet when the `puts` command is called, and partially that you are not actually used to working asynchronously.

You need to wait for something to arrive before you can print the variable out. The `vwait` command is ideal for this (as it runs the Tcl event loop while waiting). We can tell it to wait for the (global) `LIST` variable to be written to: when it has been, we can safely read it.

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    global LIST
    set data [gets $chan]
    set LIST [split $data ","]  
}

set chan [open com5 r]
fconfigure $chan -mode "9600,n,8,1" -blocking 1 -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $chan readable [list receiver $chan]

vwait LIST
puts $LIST
```

Comment: Thank you Donal Fellows. It's almost ok but the variables incoming over the serial port are updated every second and so is the LIST inside proc. But with the vwait command LIST outside proc is shown only the first time and then never again.

Comment: @Hans, why not print out the value return from the channel within the `receiver` proc itself, no need for a global variable? this feels most natural to me: `proc receiver {chan} { set data [gets $chan]; puts [split $data ","] }`?

Comment: @Hans The core of the problem is you've got a stream of data coming in _slowly_ over the serial line, and you've got to decide when to take action and what action to take. Once you've worked that out, the program you need to write follows naturally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must declare `LIST` as global in root namespace:

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    global LIST
    set data [gets $chan]
    set LIST [split $data ,]  
}

global LIST
puts $LIST  

set chan [open com5 r]
fconfigure $chan -mode "9600,n,8,1" -blocking 1 -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $chan readable [list receiver $chan]
```

Comment: Thank you, Mathieu. Unfortunately that doesn't help. Still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

> It's almost ok but the variables incoming over the serial port are
>   updated every second

If that is the requirement, then:

(1) Have the value returned from the channel be printed in the callback proc: `receiver`

(2) Enter the event loop just once, w/o binding to a global variable `List` or the like.

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    set data [gets $chan]
    puts [split $data ","]; # (1) print the return value
}

set chan [open com5 r]
fconfigure $chan -mode "9600,n,8,1" -blocking 1 -buffering none -translation binary
fileevent $chan readable [list receiver $chan]

vwait forever
puts "Quitted from event loop ..."
```

This will enter into an event loop that is bound to an undefined variable `forever`, not set from within your script. So it will not quit unless you stop the executable (e.g., `tclsh`) or unless you do not provide for an explicit ending condition, e.g.:

```
proc receiver {chan} {
    global counter
    set data [gets $chan]
    puts [split $data ","]; # (1) print the return value
    if {[incr counter] == 5} {
        global forever
        set forever 1; # (2) Exit the event loop, after receiver having been called 5 times
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, I don't see, where I can find this list in the global space. What means "puts  "Quitted from event loop ..."" exactly? Could you please explain it a bit more specific.

Comment: I think, I should make myseIf a bit clearer. I'm using `puts` just for test purposes (displaying in the console). At the end I want to display the variables in a widget. My intention is:  First create a list to get rid of the curly brackets in `data`. 2nd put this list in global namespace. 3rd assign every element of the list to a variable with `lassign`. 4th put these variables in a widget. To do the latter I think the variables need to be in the global name space.

Comment: How is this different to what you asked (and got answered) in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496444/how-to-save-incoming-variables-from-serial-port-into-a-list?

Comment: It's still the same problem. I didn't get it running last time because I didn't get 1) a proper list  and 2) of the scope problem. Then I was busy otherwise and put it aside. In the meantime I modified the transmitter sending the variables, so that I get now a correct list with this actual code. But there is still the scope problem as i tried to explain in my last comment. Or do I miss something?

Comment: First, it would have been better to continue working on your previous post, IMO. Second, did you try to run the code suggested to you? There is no "scope problem" in the above snippets. My suggestion: Run the script, if it fails, make it run (also by reaching out to us). Then, stepwise walk through the script to understand the details.

Comment: I ran your suggested code in previous post at that time, but it failed. `label...` showed `::result` Then I changed `label.l -textvar ::result` to `label.l -textvar $::result` resulting in an empty `label...`. That's the reason, why I think it's kind of a scope problem. I played around with `::` and found out that this works only in one direction, from global to proc and not vice versa. This applies also to `global`and `upvar` as I mentioned already in this actual post. Your new proposal with `vwait forever`either with or without `counter`shows `LIST` only once and not continually.

Comment: With `LIST`I mean `[split $data ","]`. I'm not sure what is meant with `puts "Quitted from event loop ..."`. When I replace it by `puts $::LIST`it shows the a.m. behaviour